# Can I validate and sanitize form data using jQuery? how so?

Tags: jquery, html, validation, forms, sanitization

Are there any methods in jQuery to validate form data? What about sanitizing the form data?

Comment: personally, I wouldn't put validation/sanitization code on the front-end.. just makes it easier for a malicious visitor to find out how to bypass it.

Comment: I also am sanitizing on the back end. It's just an email form, no DB involved. That said, you're not wrong in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's [the jQuery UI Validation plug-in](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

Comment: validation is good to do on the front end because it makes the time to alert the user shorter, but sanitization must always be done on the back end to be secure.